# Science Fiction short story(-ies) about a person who is arrested by a robot for being outside at night

Tags: story-identification, robots

When I was in high school, I read a book of short stories, I think it was sci-fi.

It was about a man who I think was the one of the last human beings on Earth. The story ends something like this... this person steps out of his house for a night walk in a deserted street when a police robot arrests him, and takes him prisoner for going for a walk in the night (I think humans were not supposed to do so, and robots were the masters of the Earth).

Comment: I know this story, it's from one of the golden-age writers. It's *not* Asimov's 
[*It's Such a Beautiful Day*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Such_a_Beautiful_Day), though the theme is similar.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229512/sci-fi-short-story-about-a-man-being-pulled-up-by-the-cops-for-walking-around (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 21):

I think I found it. It's likely Ray Bradbury's [*The Pedestrian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pedestrian).

from the Wiki article:

> In this story we encounter Leonard Mead, a citizen of a
> television-centered world in 2053. In the city, roads have fallen into
> decay. It is revealed that Mead enjoys walking through the city during
> the night, something which no one else does. "In ten years of walking
> by night or day, for thousands of miles, he had never met another
> person walking, not one in all that time." On one of his usual walks
> he encounters a police car which is possibly robotic. It is the only
> police unit in a city of three million, since the purpose of law
> enforcement has disappeared with everyone watching TV at night. Mead
> tells the car that he is a writer when asked about his profession, but
> the car does not understand, since no one buys books or magazines in
> the television-dominated society. The police car or its occupants
> struggle to understand why Mead would be out walking for no reason and
> so decides to take him to the Psychiatric Center for Research on
> Regressive Tendencies. He is forced to get in the car. As the car
> passes through his neighborhood, Leonard Mead in the locked confines
> of the backseat says, "That's my house". There is no reply.

This story was originally published August 7, 1951. It's been widely [anthologized](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56011) (to say the least).

Comment: You can read it at http://mikejmoran.typepad.com/files/pedestrian-by-bradbury-1.pdf

Comment: If you hadn't told me that was a Ray Bradbury story, I probably would have guessed it anyway.

Comment: And while I've not read _The Pedestrian_, according to his Introduction to the 50th Anniversary Edition of _Fahrenheit 451_ (which I've recently read) the pedestrian became the fireman in that book.